# How to add image attachments from sdcard in email app using javamail API

Tags: android, api, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I'm new to android programming and Android Studio, I'm developing a simple android application that can send a email with attachment. I already can send email but with the attachment part I'm having troubles. When I add the mimebodypart for the attachment I can't receive any emails now. Here's my code

**SimpleMail.java**

```
package com.team8.javamail2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


/**
 * Created by VEN on 1/27/2019.
 */
public class SimpleMail {

/**CHANGE ACCORDINGLY**/
private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "unvrsx@gmail.com"; 
private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "XXXXXXXXXX"; 

private static Message message;
private File file ;
private Context context;


public static void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String msg){
    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "unvrsx@gmail.com"; //from

    final String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
    final String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;

    // Assuming you are sending email through relay.jangosmtp.net
    String host = SMTP_HOST_NAME;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    // Get the Session object.
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(subject);

        // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        // Now set the actual message
        messageBodyPart.setContent(msg, "text/html");

        // Create a multipar message

        // Set text message part


    // Part two is attachment
        String filepath = "/storage/emulated/0/WaterMarkImages";
        String filename = "Book.xlsx";
        File att = new File(new File(filepath),filename);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
         messageBodyPart2.attachFile(att);


         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(att);
         messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
         messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);

         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
          multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        // Send the complete message partBidt
        message.setContent(multipart);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try  {

                    // Send message
                    Transport.send(message);
                    System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.team8.javamail2;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText toEmailEditText;
private EditText subjectEditText;
private EditText messageEditText;
private Button sendButton;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toEmailEditText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    subjectEditText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
    messageEditText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);


    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {


                String to = toEmailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                String subject = subjectEditText.getText().toString();
                String message = messageEditText.getText().toString();



                if(to.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must enter a     recipient email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(subject.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must enter a Subject", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(message.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must enter a message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    //everything is filled out
                    //send email
                    new SimpleMail().sendEmail(to, subject, message);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }


    });
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.team8.javamail2">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know if something around here cause the problem

```
      String filepath = "/storage/emulated/0/WaterMarkImages";
        String filename = "Book.xlsx";
        File att = new File(new File(filepath),filename);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
         messageBodyPart2.attachFile(att);


         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(att);
         messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
         messageBodyPart2.setFileName(filename);

         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
          multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
```

Comment: After calling attachFile, you don't need the following three lines; they're doing what attachFile already did.

Comment: Are you sure you can access the file?  Do you get any exceptions?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: There was no Exceptions I didn't get any error at all but I can receive the email and the attached file

Comment: I can't still receive any emails

Comment: Post the debug output.